# An integral involving a logarithm and two inverse trigonometric functions:$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \arcsin x \arctan x\log x dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

The integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \arcsin x \arctan x\log x dx$  can be explicitly computed; the result being representable in an elementary way (for instance without the appearance of polylogarithms). This was done around 2017. I would be interested in seeing a second generation proof.  This problem was asked in a disguised form as problem 1431 in Elemente der Mathematik. No complete solution involving only elementary functions (roots and logarithms)  was received.

Comment: It might be a good idea to give the closed form for the integral here (or did you intentionally exclude it for some reason?). It might also be a good idea to write out the integral in the title.

Comment: @C-RAM  I intentionally excluded the explicit form, as nested roots may have different representations

Comment: @ray Can you give a link to it if not post it?

Comment: @ Tyma Gaidash  Here are two sources: J.M. Campbell and A. Soho, in  Integral Transforms and special functions 28 (2017). 547-559 and A. Stadler, Elemente der Mathematik 79 (2024), 38-44 (solution to problem 1431).